# Detect if requested page is PWA on server side WordPress

Tags: wordpress, progressive-web-apps, query-string

I'm trying to determine if the user is browsing PWA on server side. On client side I can check if the browser mode is `standalone` via JavaScript and detect PWA, but on server side this is not an option. So I'm using simple query parameter for that. Start URL in manifest has query param `isPwa` appended and every time user opens PWA, it goes to `https://example.com/?isPwa`. What I need now is to keep that parameter while user browses PWA, so I need to set `isPwa` parameter to next URL that user opens if the referer URL already had `isPwa` parameter, but my code goes to redirection loop and I'm unable to identify the cause of this. Here's my code:

```
function addIsPwaQueryArg() {
    $referer = wp_get_referer();
    if (strpos($referer, 'isPwa') !== false) {
        $location = remove_query_arg('isPwa');
        wp_redirect(add_query_arg('isPwa', '', $location));
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'addIsPwaQueryArg');
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code and why is it not working?

Thanks!